# SQL sorting by date problem

Tags: mysql, sorting, date

I wanna sort by date; however, after I trimmed of the time part of the date. It doesn't recognize the dates. Any suggestions?

```
SELECT Count(*) AS total, 
    DATE_FORMAT(install_date, '%d-%m-%Y') AS new_date
FROM extable
GROUP BY new_date
ORDER BY new_date DESC
```

----OUTPUT-----

```
1583    31-12-2010
1180    31-10-2010
64  31-08-2010
959 31-03-2011
1520    31-01-2011
1626    30-12-2010
920 30-11-2010
1608    30-10-2010
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could also sort in the order Y-M-D instead.  That would give you the correct sorting.

Comment: I did not see your answer. Sorry!. Yes I did the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

DATE_FORMAT is converting your date into a String with the given format. You are then sorting by that String in which case, the DBMS is applying the correct sort. You should sort by install_date instead if you want to sort by date.

Comment: No, the right way to sort this is to use the raw date. This way your sorting is independent of however you are displaying the date.